# Записать данные в столбец Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi

Мне надо данные записывать по столбцам. А1, A2, A3... А POI как я понял пишет А1, В1, С1
Мой код работает не правильно, он перезаписывает ячейки и на выходе только последняя коллекция записывается правильно.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            value = iterator.next();
            rowCounter = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < value.getValue().size(); i++) {
                row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter++);
                cell = row.createCell(cellCounter);
                cell.setCellValue(value.getValue().get(i));
            }
            cellCounter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашел вот такой способ

```
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            value = iterator.next();
            int beginRow = 1;
            for (String result : value.getValue()) {
                if (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() - 1 > beginRow - 1) {
                    row = sheet.getRow(beginRow);
                } else {
                    row = sheet.createRow(beginRow);
                }
                cell = row.createCell(cellBegin);
                cell.setCellValue(result);
                beginRow++;
            }
            cellBegin++;
        }
```